# c# DeflateSream return 0;

Tags: c#, stream, compression

I'm trying to compress an image using `Defltestream` but somehow when I try to print the return buffer length it's always 0.

```
public void goo()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
    Bitmap prev;

    prev = GetDesktopImage();
    prev.Save(ms,ImageFormat.Png);
    prev.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Png);
    com = ms.ToArray();
    MessageBox.Show((com.Length / 1000).ToString() + "KB");
    MessageBox.Show(((Compress(ms2).Length/1000).ToString()+"KB"));
}
```

`GetDesktopImage` is a function which returns a screenshot. In the first messagebox it display the length (for example the output is: "350kb"), but in the second its always 0kb!

This is the compress method:

```
private static byte[] Compress(Stream input)
{
    using (var compressStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(compressStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            input.CopyTo(compressor);
            compressor.Close();
            return compressStream.ToArray();
        }
}
```

Does anyone has any idea why I'm always getting 0?

Comment: Try rewinding the input stream.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what do u mean rewinding the input stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write something to a stream (or Save in your case), its internal position is incremented accordingly.

So as Lasse V. Karlsen said, you should rewinding  the stream

```
m.Position = 0;
```

or

```
m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

to make the readers start to read from position 0.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);
var m = new MemoryStream();
b.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
Console.WriteLine(m.Position); // will output 169
```

Comment: where to use the reset position liine? in my call? in the compress method itself? @EZI

Comment: @itapi before starting to read the stream, for ex, before calling *Compress* (MemoryStream supports *Seek* but not every stream, So calling it on MemoryStream is better.)

Comment: one last thing,i  just looked up in some places i couldnt find a method to decompress  a byre array using deflatedstream. if you could help me i will really apperciate it @EZI

Comment: well? do you know how to? @EZI

Comment: @itapi `private static byte[] Decompress(Stream input)
        {
            var s = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
            s.CopyTo(m);
            return m.ToArray();
        }` I omitted using's. I think you can add them,

Answer (score 0):

I think it shows zero, but the value is not zero. When you divide integer or integer is divided by a number the result is always an integer. And when the value of the integer is decimal, it will convert the value to non decimal number (round).

### sample:

```
int number = 25;`
return number / 2;
```

the result will be 13, because the value was 12.5 and it changed to integer value by rounding and that gives us 13

Comment: even this still displays zero `  MessageBox.Show(((Compress(ms2).Length).ToString()+"KB"));` even if im not diving it @JanSkála

Comment: @itapi Is your problem really *integer division*. If so I will delete my answer.

Comment: @EZI not its not... i  wrote here, even if i do not divie the buffer length. yo actually solve it but now im looking for way to decompress the data